# Review queues completed message not appearing

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, review

Once I finished the Review Queues, as explained in the title of this post, *nothing* shows up when I finish them. Refreshing, *nor* *restarting* the website did not fix this problem:

[image]

As far as I'm concerned, whenever you finish Review Queues, you usually get a message around the lines of:

- You have completed this queue!

And this message does not appear, just a short white screen.

Comment: Same result on my end, added the status-review tag.

Comment: Reported on the main meta: ["This queue has been cleared" message is no longer being displayed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369525/241919)

Comment: @AkiTanaka so i would assume this is a problem/bug across SE, not just A&M? while i dont get some error message like the OP does, ive only recently started seeing this bug

Comment: @Dimitrimx yes, it's a network-wide issue and it's relatively new bug (possibly related to the recent revamp to the review queues)

Comment: @AkiTanaka That *is* a possibility, but what about the queue left untouched (Late answers queue)? it happens to every review queue i have access to. (also did you mean @ daniel?)

Comment: Completing another review does not fix this problem as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This bug has been fixed.**

According to the [Kristina Lustig's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369966/241919)

> I fixed this today (Sep 17). The problem was that we were mistakenly returning `null` instead of a partial `EmptyTask.cshtml` due (I think) to a refactor gone awry. Since it's Friday afternoon here, this won't be shipped until early next week, but I'll mark it as status-completed because the work is done and it's on its way. Thank you for reporting!

However, the fix was [deployed not earlier than Sep 22](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369525/this-queue-has-been-cleared-message-is-no-longer-being-displayed#comment1235280_369966),

> This also affected my browser @JitendraSingh but has been fixed in the past few minutes; it was still broken a half hour ago. – Rob Sep 22 at 16:34